# Fatal error: Call to a member function get_tab() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\relation\application\controllers\c_relation.php on line 7

Tags: codeigniter

I got this problem, I researched more but didn't find any solution .
I am creating a Database relation logic For Crud .

Model code is :

```
<?php

class M_relation extends CI_Model{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_tab(){
        $query = $this->db->get('user_id');
        return $query->result_array() ;
    }
}
```

And Controller Code is :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_relation extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
    $this->load->model('m_relation');
    $data['user_id'] = $this->M_relation->get_tab();
    echo var_dump($data['id']);
    $this->load->view('v_relation');
}
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_relation');
}

}
?>
```

Please :)

Comment: m_relation->get_tab (all small)

Comment: It didn't worked ! 
will you please clarify the answer. :)

Comment: M_relation is the name of the class ! 
it Cannot be small ! the class first latter is capital .

Comment: replace M_relation to m_relation and also rename your model name with m_relation. try it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->get('user');
```

Instead

```
$query = $this->db->get('user_id');
```

The mistake was that i set the get() to user_id its a table field .
instead of table name .

Answer (score 0):

please replace

```
$this->load->model('m_relation');
```

to

```
$this->load->model('M_relation');
```

You load model as m_relation but when you access function using M_relation.